# How to access secured geoserver services

Tags: geoserver

I have geoserver and i have many maps(layers) but i want to secure this layers and i want to access this layers. I searched that but result is not working for example one of samples is "http://username:password@ipadress/geoserver" but when i tried to access like that geoserver return me 404 error but when i login, server return succesfully.

Second of samples for accessing server : That's my proxy

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Proxy(string url)
{
    var context = this.HttpContext;


    //var dUrl = url.Replace("http://", "");
    var dUrl = url;
    dUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(dUrl);
    //var hede = new Uri(dUrl, UriKind.Relative);
    var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;


    String username = "admin";
    String password = "geoserver";
    String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);


    if (request.Method == "POST")
    {
        var content = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd());

        request.ContentLength = content.Length;
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }

    var response = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    if (response == null)
        return null; // new JsonResult();

    context.Response.Write(new System.IO.StreamReader(response).ReadToEnd());

    return null; //Json(new JsonResult(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

}

Comment: Please add a language tag to your question.  Also it sounds like you're just using a bad URL.

Comment: You should use "geoserver" not "geoserver server". Server is already in its name. Unless geoserver is not a server at all. Passing passwords in plaintext in a url is incredibly risky. Are you sure that's the correct way to access data.

Comment: My url is runnig correctly if i logined , but when i logout and try to get data with proxy ,it gives me error

Comment: i dont know it is correct way ,it is not working exactly, Do you know any other ways?